# MERN Stack with Email Authentication - Verification link works only on First User

Tags: email, stack, mern, verify, email-verification

i have a mern-stack authentication with email verification system. If the first person signs up and takes the verification link, it works perfect. If a second user Sign Up and take the verification link, when press it it doesn't work. Im getting Error 500 with axioserror.

here is the router.js: https://github.com/prjwlbadwe/AuthInMern-Email-Verify-In-MERN/blob/main/server/routes/users.js

and the verify page: https://github.com/prjwlbadwe/AuthInMern-Email-Verify-In-MERN/blob/main/client/src/components/EmailVerify/index.jsx

If you want to see other files, there are on github link.